# D3 Transitions: Complex Transition Lags Behind Simpler Transition

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am working on creating a d3 animation where points on a 2d plane move along a pre-determined path, and I have been attempting to implement a polyline that will dynamically transform to encapsulate all of the points as they move around the plane (using [giftwrapping alg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gift_wrapping_algorithm)).

I have noticed that as I increase the amount of time for the animation to run, the polyline begins to lag behind the points. It still seems to be accurate, however, it looks like the polyline transition cannot "keep up" with the transition of the points. The amount of lag increases proportionately the longer I specify the animation to run.

I was under the assumption that all of the data for the animation was calculated before the animation would begin playing, and that the animation would simply run through the list of pre-caluclated data which would make the lagging difficult to explain. Is this not so?

I can provide some example code if necessary.

Thanks!

Comment: The animation is computed per frame, i.e. for every animation frame a function is called that returns the current state. There's no precalculation.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Just what I needed to know.